# Is thre a difference between the tags [sun] and [the-sun]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

What is the difference (if any) between the tags [sun](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sun) and [the-sun](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-sun)?

Should they be merged, or do they refer to different topics?

Note that there is currently zero overlap between the two tags; no question uses both.

Comment: Nice find.  [the-sun] is clearly about Sol.  I suspected [sun] could be used for stars of other planetary systems.  However, after examining all 17 [sun] questions, only one used it that way, and that one question was closed as off-topic.  So it looks like both tags refer to Sol.

Comment: @DrSheldon *Which one?* If you found a bit of information helpful for formulating an answer why not share it? In fact, why not propose they be merged as an answer? It seems like the right thing to do, and I'll be more sure when I know to which of the 17 [sun] questions you are referring ;-)

Comment: @uhoh While you are right that it would have been helpful for Dr Sheldon to provide that information, I went ahead and untagged the question referred to. This is definitely a duplicate situation. I'm going to merge them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have performed the merge and synonymization.